# Adding values of two columns in dataframe unintentional changes header of result column

Tags: r

I have a data frame and want to add a "total" column with the result of the sum of the rows.

Starting point:

```
var1 var2
  1    2
  1    2
  1    2
```

Desired result:

```
var1 var2 total
  1    2    3
  1    2    3
  1    2    3
```

My code does that but changes the name of the header of the "total" column to the header of var1 column. Why? What could be a better solution?

Here is my code:

```
df<-data.frame( "var1"=c(1,1,1), "var2"=c(2,2,2))
df["total"]<-0

for (i in 1:2 ){
  df$total = df$total + df[i] 
}
df
```

Result:

```
var1 var2 **var1**
  1    2    3
  1    2    3
  1    2    3
```

Comment: `df$Total <- rowSums(df)`

Comment: Thanks! But any idea why the header is overwritten?

Comment: You need to add a vector rather a data frame. `df$total = df$total + df[[i]] `. Compare: `df[1]` and  `df[[1]]`, since `df$total` is a vector too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct ways to do it are:

```
df$total = df$var1 + df$var2
df[["total"]] = df[["var1"]] + df[["var2"]]
```

note the double brackets, your solution will work if you use double brackets instead of single brackets

as Ronak suggested:

```
df$total = rowSums(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can youe the `mutate()`-function

```
library(tidyverse)

df<-df%>%mutate(total=rowsum(var1,var2))

> df
  var1 var2 total
1    1    2     3
2    1    2     3
3    1    2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work and it won't rename your column. `[i]` returns a `data frame` where as `[[i]]` returns a `numeric`. So, you want to add individual numbers.

```r
df<-data.frame( "var1"=c(1,1,1), "var2"=c(2,2,2))
df["total"]<-0

for (i in 1:2){
  df$total = df$total + df[[i]] 
}
```